# Remove an object from an object array using index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to remove 3rd object from an array in which the color is red. I want to remove it using the index as some objects may not have an _id attribute and other attributes are not unique among them.

```
[
  {  color: "BLUE"
     imageURL: "/uploads/image-1639632524718.png"
     inStock: 4
     _id: "61b9bff23b027548ed2f737e"
  },
  {  color: "green"
     imageURL: "/uploads/image-1639561204805.png"
     inStock: 6
     _id: "61ba098f3b027548ed2f737f"
  },
  {  color: "Red"
     imageURL: "/uploads/image-1639647424471.png"
     inStock: 6
  },
  {  color: "Star Light"
     imageURL: "/uploads/image-1639650244179.png"
     inStock: 60
  }
]
```

After removing the object array will look like.

```
[
  {  color: "BLUE"
     imageURL: "/uploads/image-1639632524718.png"
     inStock: 4
     _id: "61b9bff23b027548ed2f737e"
  },
  {  color: "green"
     imageURL: "/uploads/image-1639561204805.png"
     inStock: 6
     _id: "61ba098f3b027548ed2f737f"
  },
  {  color: "Star Light"
     imageURL: "/uploads/image-1639650244179.png"
     inStock: 60
  }
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: _"I want to remove 3rd object from an array in which the color is red"_ - What if the "3rd" object is not "red"? _"I want to remove it using the index as some objects may not have an _id attribute..."_ - How is the `_id` relevant for this? _"...other attributes are not unique among them."_ - What? And how is that relevant?

Comment: I mean I want to delete the object using index @Andreas

Comment: Doesn't answer any of my questions. Why index? Why not just `.filter()` for the color?

Comment: Cause many objects can have the same color but I want to remove only one of them, not all have the same color. @Andreas

Comment: What if the "3rd" object is not "red"?

Comment: No problem @Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Once you've fixed your data structure - it's not an array, and you're missing commas...)

You can [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out all those objects that aren't located at that index.

```js
const data=[{color:"BLUE",imageURL:"/uploads/image-1639632524718.png",inStock:4,_id:"61b9bff23b027548ed2f737e"},{color:"green",imageURL:"/uploads/image-1639561204805.png",inStock:6,_id:"61ba098f3b027548ed2f737f"},{color:"Red",imageURL:"/uploads/image-1639647424471.png",inStock:6},{color:"Star Light",imageURL:"/uploads/image-1639650244179.png",inStock:60}];

const out = data.filter((obj, i) => i !== 2);

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

this `splice` function does that

someArray.splice(index, 1)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.splice()` method to remove item from specified position.

```js
const list = [
  {  color: "BLUE",
     imageURL: "/uploads/image-1639632524718.png",
     inStock: 4,
     _id: "61b9bff23b027548ed2f737e"
  },
  {  color: "green",
     imageURL: "/uploads/image-1639561204805.png",
     inStock: 6,
     _id: "61ba098f3b027548ed2f737f"
  },
  {  color: "Red",
     imageURL: "/uploads/image-1639647424471.png",
     inStock: 6
  },
  {  color: "Star Light",
     imageURL: "/uploads/image-1639650244179.png",
     inStock: 60
  }
];

const remove = (arr, index) => arr.splice(index, 1);
remove(list, 2);
console.log("list after removal: ", list);
```